# Doctrine не хватает памяти на join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine2, dql

Пишу DQL запрос в Doctrine:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT adsLink
                           FROM CatalogBundle:AdsLink adsLink
                           JOIN CatalogBundle:Product product
                           WHERE product.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user);

    return $query->getResult();
```

И у меня падает сайт, один раз показало что недостаточно памяти для PDO

Аналогичный запрос на SQL работает мгновенно:

```
SELECT product_advertising_link.*, products.name, products.user_id
FROM product_advertising_link
JOIN products ON product_advertising_link.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.user_id = 1
```

Comment: А где вы в DQL потеряли условие объединения? Декартово произведение же получили.

Answer (score 0):

Заменил JOIN на WHERE

```
SELECT adsLink
FROM CatalogBundle:AdsLink adsLink, CatalogBundle:Product product
WHERE adsLink.product = product
AND product.user = :user
```